# UITextField into UITableViewCell auto reset when scroll down and turn back?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uitextfield

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have more `UITextField` into `UITableViewCell` but when I scroll down and I turn back the `UITextField` is empty. There is a way for not auto reset?

This is the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cella"];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cella"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [dati objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITextField *testo = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 31)];
    testo.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    testo.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    testo.placeholder = @"Inserisci del testo..";
    testo.delegate = self;

    cell.accessoryView = testo;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's re-creating the cell every time. That is why every time it is creating new cell and reinitialize contained controls where you might not have put condition if a UITextField contains text, it should not clear its text.

Comment: You have to maintain a MutableDictionary which contains text for each separate UITextField text. As next time the method is going to call, you have to check whether text for that row's UITextfield is exist or not and set text property accordingly. Getting my point?